# Can a PhD student publish a paper outside PhD topic without supervisor approval only by its own?

Tags: paper-submission

I am a theoretical PhD student. Is it possible to submit and to publish papers in journals without supervisor approval? I am asking also from legal point of view, as well. I have talked to many people in my university and some of them don't have  a good opinion regarding single author papers since such a single author paper might have sufficient errors in it. However, the subject is not studied by anyone in the university.

Comment: Do you think your supervisor would tell you not to submit it?  If so, why?  Have you asked him/her?

Comment: **Of course you can.** If it's your own completely independent work, nobody can ethically prevent you from submitting it for publication, university regulations to the contrary be damned.  As a PhD student, I submitted journal papers without seeking my advisor's **permission** first; so did my advisor, and so do my own PhD students.  That said, seeking your advisor's **feedback, advice, and encouragement** before submission is strongly recommended, both to double-check the quality of the paper and to maintain a good relationship with your advisor.

Comment: @David Ketcheson yes, this is the main reason as to why I didn't asked the supervisor. I was thinking about telling about the paper only if it is accepted.

Comment: @JeffE As previously stated, this is outside the supervisor field, I don't think the supervisor would put effort into a new area which would require a significant amount of time(my supervisor is the head of the department and has limited time for research).

Comment: @MikeyMike Sounds like you need a new advisor.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no general reason why this should not be possible/allowed.

You will have to check the regulations of your department/university for PhD students: They may require you to seek approval of your advisor prior to submission of papers. Potentially a journal could have a similar rule in place, but I have never encountered this.

That said, I do not believe this to be advisable: If your relationship with your PhD advisor is so bad that do you not feel you can ask them about your intention to submit this paper, you should probably seek a new advisor. If you are so close to graduating that your prefer sitting it out, then rocking the boat is probably a bad idea.

Comment: Regarding the supervisor, the faculty won't admit changing the supervisor. My supervisor is not so close with his phd students. Another student of my supervisor submitted a paper to Nature and it's under review(3rd round) without telling a thing to the supervisor.

Comment: "Someone else has done this and has been successful" is absolutely not a good reason to continue doing this. If the advisor is apathetic to his students, that's one thing, but there's no reason not to notify him and ask if he has any advice or thoughts. If he doesn't respond, sure, whatever, but at least you tried. I'd advise that at least, try to be diplomatic and cover your ass.

Comment: @Sergio We have no idea whether the superviser is helpful or hostile, s/he may be indifferent. Clearly the OP does not feel the superviser is the first, but the right behaviour may depend on being the second or third and on school regulations.

Comment: @Captain Emacs what do you mean by the first, second, third?

Comment: @MikeyMike I meant: 1. helpful 2. hostile 3. indifferent. So, if you think the superviser is not helpful, then what to do depends on whether they are hostile or indifferent.